# Search for items and return the first item found in master item list in js

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, the first list contains a master list of all names:

```
const masterNames = [
"Adam", 
"Owen",
"Dylan",
"Luke",
"Gabriel",
"Anthony",
"Isaac",
"Grayson",
"Jack",
"Julian",
"Levi",
];
```

and another list which contains specific names:

```
const students = ["Steve", "Dylan", "Luke"]
```

I want to search the master list and return the first name from students that is found in the master list. In this case "Dylan" since Steve is not on the list.

```js
    const students = ["Steve", "Dylan", "Luke"];
    const masterNames = [
    "Adam", 
    "Owen",
    "Dylan",
    "Luke",
    "Gabriel",
    "Anthony",
    "Isaac",
    "Grayson",
    "Jack",
    "Julian",
    "Levi",
    ];

    
    masterNames.forEach(function (item, index) {
       const found = students.find(element => element === item);
       console.log(found);
    });
```

I used `Array.prototype.find()` inside a loop but it returns all name and not just the first item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the first single name that matches you can use `find()` and `includes()`

```js
const students = ["Steve", "Dylan", "Luke"];
const masterNames = ["Adam", "Owen", "Dylan", "Luke", "Gabriel", "Anthony", "Isaac", "Grayson", "Jack", "Julian", "Levi",];

const result = students.find(student => masterNames.includes(student));

console.log(result);
```

If you think you might need the remaining matching names you can [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `students` array by whether the `masterNames` array [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) it and take the first element in the result, here using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const students = ["Steve", "Dylan", "Luke"];
const masterNames = ["Adam", "Owen", "Dylan", "Luke", "Gabriel", "Anthony", "Isaac", "Grayson", "Jack", "Julian", "Levi",];

const includedStudents = students.filter(s => masterNames.includes(s));
const [result] = includedStudents;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` twice to find the first student name in the master names list.

```js
const students = ["Steve", "Dylan", "Luke"];
const masterNames = [
  "Adam",
  "Owen",
  "Dylan",
  "Luke",
  "Gabriel",
  "Anthony",
  "Isaac",
  "Grayson",
  "Jack",
  "Julian",
  "Levi",
];


let found = masterNames.find(function(item) {
  return students.find(element => element === item);
});

console.log(found)
```

**Update**

The more elegant answer is using `.find()` and `.includes()` like pilchard answer shows. Keeping my answer up as an alternative method.